# how to get this CAML query to work

Tags: caml

I have a javascript and i can't get the CAML or listitems.

```
//http://vadimtabakman.com/nintex-forms-multilingual-form.aspx

NWF$(document).ready(function () {
    var language = NWF$('#' + varLanguage);

    language.change(function() {
    //alert(language).val(); // else alert error message

    var languageValue = this.value.split(";#")[1];
    alert(languageValue);

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Survey Label Translation');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    alert('line 15');
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View>' +
            '<Query>' +
                '<Where>' + 
                    '<Eq>' +
                        '<FieldRef Name=\'Language\'/><Value Type=\'Choice\'>' + Spanish + '</Value>' +
                    '</Eq>' +
                '</Where>' +
            '</Query>' +
        '</View>'
        );  
    alert('line 26');
    this.collListItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItems);  
    alert('line 30');
    alert(collListItems.status);
    if (collListItems.status == 200)
     {
       var rows = collListItems.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('z:row');

       for(x=0; x < rows.length; x++)
       {
         var listLabelID = rows[x].getAttribute('ows_Title'); // query field + ows prefix
         var listTranslation = rows[x].getAttribute('ows_Translation'); // query field + ows prefix
         translations[listLabelID] = listTranslation;
         var node = NWF$('.' + listLabelID).find('.nf-label-control');
         node.text(listTranslation);
       }
     }
     else
     {
       alert('There was an error: ' + collListItems.statusText); // else alert error message
     }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the filter is confusing. although the field type is choice you have change it to Text like below and wala

```
 '<FieldRef Name=\'Language\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + languageValue + '</Value>' +
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things in there...

First of all, I'm surprised you're not getting an error message `Spanish is not defined.`

In your CAML code, you have the word "Spanish", outside of quotes, so it's not being treated as a string, it would be treated as a variable name.

I think maybe what you want in there is:

```
'<FieldRef Name=\'Language\'/><Value Type=\'Choice\'>' + languageValue + '</Value>' +
```

Secondly, although you build up your query and request for stuff from SharePoint, you never actually send off the query to the server to get processed.  After you do `context.load(stuffYouWant)` you still have to `context.executeQueryAsync()` to send the request to the server.

Keep in mind `executeQueryAsync` takes two arguments - the success callback and the failure callback.

Check out this documentation on [`executeQueryAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn168907(v%3Doffice.15)) and this [other example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14)) of how to retrieve list items.

Comment: I can't get the following to work     var rows = collListItems.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('z:row');
    
     for(x=0; x < rows.length; x++)

Comment: The `z:row` thing comes into play when you are using the old 2010 `ListData.svc` endpoint, which is used by the popular `SPServices` library.  However, you do not seem to be using SPServices, you are using the regular SP2013 CSOM library.  Again, I would suggest you look at the example I linked to in my answer, it shows how to call `executeQueryAsync` with the callback functions, and in the success callback, use `getEnumerator()` and `moveNext()` to loop through the items. What happens if you `console.log(collListItems)` just before you try to get the rows out of it?  What do you see?